# how to write unit test case for ternary condition using MSTest C# .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, mstest

```
public static Transaction Update(Transaction authData, CreateArguments arguments)
{
    if (authData == null) return null;

    **authData.CampaignId = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arguments.CampaignId) ? authData.CampaignId : arguments.CampaignId;
    authData.Status = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arguments.Status) ? authData.Status : arguments.Status;**
    authData.DateModified = DateHelper.GpgNow();
    return authData;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Update_WhenTransactionObjIsNull()
{
    var argument = new Transaction.CreateArguments();
    var response = Transaction.Update(null, argument);
    Assert.IsNull(response);
}
```

I have the Update() method and setting CampaignId and Status using ternary condition. and below [TestMethod] is written.
How can i add unit test case for those ternary condition. Please help

Comment: That's no different than asking how to test an `if/else`. Write different tests, with different input that exercise all branches and check if the result is the one you expected

Comment: Which unit test framework are you using? `TestMethod` isn't an NUnit attribute. MSTest has such an attribute. Different unit test libraries have different ways to pass data to tests. In NUnit you can use [TestCase](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcase.html) to run the same test with different data

Comment: In MSTest the equivalent to `TestCase` is `DataRow`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it's MSTest. can you please write a sample for above condition. I am new to unit test.

Comment: Check the [Inline data-driven test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2022#inline-data-driven-test) paragraph in the MSTest docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most unit test frameworks allow passing data to unit tests. In MSTest this is done using the `DataRow` attribute. You can pass different value combinations for campaign and status and check whether the resulting object's properties match what you expected.

You can test the method for different Campaign ID values like this

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow("","DefaultID")]
[DataRow(null,"DefaultID")]
[DataRow("1234","1234")]
public void Update_For_CampId(string? campId,string expectedCampId)
{
    var transaction=new Transaction()
    {
        CampaignId="DefaultID",
        Status="DefaultStatus"
    };
    var argument = new Transaction.CreateArguments();
    
    argument.CampaignId=campId;
    argument.Status="SomeStatus";

    var response = Transaction.Update(transaction, argument);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCampId,response.CampaignId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedStatus,response.Status);
}
```

Testing Status is similar :

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow("","DefaultStatus")]
[DataRow(null,"DefaultStatus")]
[DataRow("OK","OK")]
public void Update_For_Status(string? status, string expectedStatus)
{
    var transaction=new Transaction()
    {
        CampaignId="DefaultID",
        Status="DefaultStatus"
    };
    var argument = new Transaction.CreateArguments();
    
    argument.CampaignId="SomeID";
    argument.Status=status;

    var response = Transaction.Update(transaction, argument);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCampId,response.CampaignId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedStatus,response.Status);
}
```

Comment: But instead of writing different test cases, how can we write all test in a single Test method.

Comment: Like, If i have 10 conditions and writing 10 different test would be lengthy. So, is there any way so that i can write all the test cases in single Test Method.

Comment: That suggests the conditions should go into their own separate methods. I already showed how you can pass multiple parameters with `DataRow`. You could try creating a single test, passing all relevant parameters,  but then you'd have to use N^3 `DataRow` attributes to pass all combinations. You can use the `DynamicData` attribute shown in the same page with a generator function to generate all combinations.